# Proving that $I-EA^{-1} = I+EA^{-1} + o(RelError(\tilde{A},A))$

Tags: asymptotics, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a non-singular matrix and let $\tilde{A} = A-E$ be an approximation of $A$. The relative error of this approximation is $$RelError(\tilde{A},A) = \frac{\| \tilde{A}-A\|}{\|A\|} = \frac{\|E\|}{\|A\|}.$$

In my book, they say that $$(I-EA^{-1})^{-1} = I + EA^{-1} + o(RelError(\tilde{A},A)).$$

I know that $(I-EA^{-1})^{-1} = I + EA^{-1} + (EA^{-1})^2 + (EA^{-1})^3+\ldots$, so this means $(EA^{-1})^2 + (EA^{-1})^3+\ldots = o(RelError(\tilde{A},A)) = o\Big(\frac{\|E\|}{\|A\|}\Big)$. Using the definition of the little oh, I just need to prove that $$\lim_{E\to 0} \frac{(EA^{-1})^2 + (EA^{-1})^3+\ldots}{\frac{\|E\|}{\|A\|}} = \|A\|\cdot \lim_{E\to 0} \frac{(EA^{-1})^2 + (EA^{-1})^3+\ldots}{\|E\|} = 0.$$

To be honest, I never worked with a limit of matrices, not sure how to proceed from here. I hope you can help me here, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe you can use this: $$\|A\|\lim_{\|E\|\to 0}\|\frac{(EA^{-1})^2 + (EA^{-1})^3+\ldots}{\|E\|}\|\le\|A\|\lim_{\|E\|\to 0}\|\frac{\|(EA^{-1})^2\| + \|(EA^{-1})^3\|+\ldots}{\|E\|}\|=$$ $$=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|^2\lim_{\|E\|\to 0}\|\frac{\|E\|^2 + \|E\|^3\|(A^{-1})\|+\ldots}{\|E\|}\|=$$
$$=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|^2\lim_{\|E\|\to 0}({\|E\| + \|E\|^2\|(A^{-1})\|+\ldots})$$
If we want this equation $$(I-EA^{-1})^{-1} = I + EA^{-1} + (EA^{-1})^2 + (EA^{-1})^3+\ldots$$ we need $\|EA^{-1}\|<1$.
That means $\|EA^{-1}\| + \|(EA^{-1})\|^2 + \|(EA^{-1})\|^3+\ldots$ converges to $\gamma$.
And now we have $$\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|^2\lim_{\|E\|\to 0}({\|E\| + \|E\|^2\|(A^{-1})\|+\ldots})=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|^2\lim_{\|E\|\to 0}({\|E\| + \|E\|*\gamma})=0$$

Comment: I'm not sure either, but let's say I am. In this case we should prove that the second limit is equal to zero. How can we prove that? Also, it's not a strict inequality.

Comment: I edited my answer, now it shoud be ok.

Comment: The inequality is still strict, this is not the case. Also, why the last limit is zero? Couldn't be the case that the sequence $\|(A^{-1})^n\|$ goes to infinity faster than $\|E\|^{n-1}$ goes to zero?

Comment: Yeah I was wrong, check now.

Comment: It's not true that $\|A\|\cdot\|A^{-1}\| = 1$